# Joomla not sending emails

Tags: php, email, joomla, phpmailer

I'm completely new to working with Joomla, I have just been asked to look at a Joomla 2.5 site which has been cloned to a new Digital Ocean Server.

It is working in the same way as the original except it won't send e-mails.

When you sign up as a new user you are supposed to get an email with log in details.

It seems to do everything perfectly, no error messages are shown but the emails never arrive...

the config file for joomla is set to 'mail' - which I understand is PHPMailer.

Does anyone know what could be causing this - has something been missed when they were transferring the site to Digital Ocean - (ssmtp has been installed and works from commandline- but would we also need something else installed such as sendmail/ postfix/ dovecot?)

this is a really old site which has been worked on by at least 5 different devs and it's in a bit of a muddle! I'm hoping someone with Joomla knowledge may be able to point me in the correct direction :)

The plan is to migrate this site then build a new up to date one - but we need this working in the mean time!

Comment: Since it is using PHPMail, I would set it up to log emails to give your more information to troubleshoot.  In php.ini, try mail.log = /home/USERNAME/public_html/mail_log but update the path to correct

Comment: Check whether the PHP versions changed. Joomly 2.5 is very old and no longer supported. PHP 7 will cause troubles for Joomla 2.5

Comment: @user3154108 - we're running on PHP 5  - it is a very old site!